# Bootswatch theme that looks the same as on the website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, bootswatch

I am trying to get the same theme working as here: http://bootswatch.com/yeti/

However I would like to use the CDN version of bootstrap/bootswatch. One is available here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/
They also host the "yeti" theme that I would like to use.

However I am unable to get it working the way I think it should be.

What I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap CDN</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- main container -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
              <h1 id="type">Typography</h1>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

For simplicity, I would like to only show a title for now. But that title looks different than the one from the http://bootswatch.com/yeti/ website. Especially the font size.
What I have to do in order to make it look the same is to add this line to the header:

```
<link href="http://bootswatch.com/assets/css/bootswatch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I think this css is some kind of internal bootswatch css file that is hosted for the bootswatch.com website itself only and should not be used.

Of course I could download the bootswatch.min.css file and load it in the header.
However, as it is nowhere stated to do that, I think this is the wrong way? What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing `http:` from all URL references in the template - it's possible that you're loading the CSS from an HTTP resource, but the font file is loading from HTTPS.

Comment: Please supply a link to the page that you want your page to look like; I had the same issue, and I think I know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the font they're using on that bootswatch page for headings is **Open Sans**. Are you loading this font using a service like [Google Web Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)?

Comment: The Bootswatch CSS file imports the font CSS, so this isn't the issue, however, I suspect it has something to do with the font not loading.